# Email validation error within a script due to the `@` sign in the filter value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Running into an "Unexpected character" error when trying to do email validation due to the `@` sign in the `var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;` line.

How would you suggest checking the string value in `str` against the `filter` value when we're unable to include the `@` character?

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script>
function checkemail() {
        var str = $('#fromEmail').val();
        var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        if (filter.test(str))
            testresults = true;
        else {
            alert("Please input a valid email address!");
            testresults = false;
        }
        return (testresults);
    }
</script>
```

The checkemail function is being called from the following script when a carousel's radio button is selected:

```
<script>
    $('[name="checkboxTAC"]').on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    ....
    if (checkemail()) {
        $('#accordion-ninth').slideToggle();
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Can you use the html5 email input type? `<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">`

Comment: I am not seeing such an error message (testing with https://jsfiddle.net/59z945bx/  ) What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Maybe the @ is getting interpreted by the page processing engine (assuming MS Razor w/ C#?) so that the client side never gets it. Have you examine the clientside source to confirm that your RegEx is received by the client uncorrupted?

Comment: It looks like I needed to add an additional `@` sign was needed. The input type="email" might have been another way to solve it but I wasn't sure if that would affect things later down the line in terms of getting the .text/.html from those fields. I'll probably still explore that method though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a cshtml page (per your post, _Layout.cshtml), you need to double up the @ symbol:

```
var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
```

Here's screenshots showing the difference:

[image]

HTH,

-Ted

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)